What are and aren't reportable transaction for Form 5472?
I have a WY LLC, which is a diregarded entity, I am a non US citizen and non resident. I do not sell in the US.
Which transactions are and aren't reportable transactions? What are some examples of transactions that aren't reportable?
What is the goal of this form?
For example:

Buying supplies on Amazon
Paying a person for services rendered
Paying dividends to myself
Paying a salary or services to myself (for service rendered to my own LLC)
Buying stocks on the stock market
Receiving payments from an EU company for services rendered

My country has a bilateral agreement with the US, which excludes double taxation and caps taxes for dividents at 5%.
I read the form and to me its not clear what is and isn't a reportable transaction.
It seems only section 4 is relevant in my case (I pay for the registered agent, formation, etc. personally, not with the LLC, for now).
Where do I put costs the LLC pays?
Where do I put revenue from services rendered?
Am I myself a foreign related party?
Is my client in EU (not myself) a related party?


This is out of scope for personal finance, you're asking about business accounting here. I suggest you talk to a CPA.
